# JSHint warning: Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics. (document, reader)

Tags: javascript, loops, jshint

I have just set up JSHint on my project and it is warning me about:

`Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics. (document, reader)`

How could I rearrange my code below to settle this issue and keep JSHint happy?

I am writing to ES6 spec.

```js
const imageUploadPreview = document.getElementById('image-upload-preview');


for (const file of files) {

let reader = new FileReader();

reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
reader.onloadend = () => {
    let previewDiv = document.createElement('div');
    previewDiv.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + reader.result + ')';
    imageUploadPreview.append(previewDiv);
};

}
```

UPDATE

Based on Ruben's answer below I ended up with the following:

```js
const imageUploadPreview = document.getElementById('image-upload-preview');

function processFile(file) {

    if (file === undefined) {
        return;
    }

    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = () => {
        let previewDiv = document.createElement('div');
        previewDiv.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + reader.result + ')';
        imageUploadPreview.append(previewDiv);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}

for (const file of files) {
    processFile(file);
}
```

This passes all of JSHints tests and works as per my previous code.

Tony.

Comment: Incidentally, I was running into the same issue as you and managed to make it pass the JSHints test with an approach similar to yours. But I don't understand why the second appraoch makes it pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-use the Filereader with recursion to avoid the loop, like they did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30768494/5015356):

```js
const imageUploadPreview = document.getElementById('image-upload-preview');

processFile(fileList) {
  const file = fileList.pop();
  if (file === undefined) {
    return;
  }

  reader.onloadend = () => {
    let previewDiv = document.createElement('div');
    previewDiv.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + reader.result + ')';
    imageUploadPreview.append(previewDiv);
    
    // Call the next function in the recursion
    processFile(fileList);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
}

processFile(files);
```

Comment: Could you explain why? I changed `files[i]` to `file` if that was the reason

Comment: because you treat an asynchronous action as synchronous.

Comment: Yeah, the first one complains about the readAsDataURL object being busy reading Blobs. Second one first complains about an unexpected { then once I add 'function' in front of 'processfile' I get an error saying fileList.pop is not a function.

Comment: Is `files` an Array? Try calling the function with `processFile(Array.from(files))`

Comment: I managed to get it working based off your code (see original posts edit) - if it can be cleaned up then great, but for my purposes it passes all tests and works as expected - thanks.

Comment: I don't understand how this would pass and the other would not, but glad to know it works. The only comment I would have is to use `url(${reader.result})` instead as the background image